# Convergence of $ \int_0^{\infty} x^{-5a} \ln(1+x^{2a}) dx $

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, such that integral is convergence.
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^{-5a} \ln(1+x^{2a}) dx
$$

$a \leq 0$ is easy, so assume $a > 0$.

My first attempt was unsuccessful.
$
\int_0^{\infty} x^{-5a} \ln(1+x^{2a}) dx < \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-3a}
$
It isn't helpful.
So I was thinking about integration by parts. It was looking hopeful, but didn't give me result. $\int \ln 1 + x^{2a}$ isn't readable. Without that, I have

$$
\left.\left(\frac{x^{-5a+1}}{-5a+1} \ln(1+x^{2a}) \right) \right|_{0}^{\infty} + \frac{2a}{1-5a}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-5a+1}}{(1+x^{2a})} dx
$$

[Above is **mistake** in derivative of $x^{2a}$, what made problem harder. **Please, look down.**]

So, for $\frac{1}{5}$ I'll have to check separately. Now I can take $a \neq \frac{1}{5}$.

I can check, when first part of sum is convergence. As this is just a limit. So we can look only for $a \geq \frac{1}{5}$. Edit:
And cause $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 0$, $a \in [\frac{1}{5}; \frac{1}{3}]$.

For $a > \frac{1}{5}$ we have $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-5a+1}}{(1+x^{2a})}dx < \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^{2a})} dx$, so for $a > \frac{1}{2}$ we have convergence of integral from sum, as $c > 1 \Longrightarrow\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^c} \in \mathbb{R}$. What I have proven. [Was question about hints.]
And we have divergence for $a > \frac{1}{2}$.

So I'm not sure, how should I deal with $a = \frac{1}{5}$. Why given integral converges or not?

And why for $a \in (\frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{3})$ integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-5a+1}}{(1+x^{2a})} dx$ convergence?

How can I prove divergence on $(0; \frac{1}{5})\cup [\frac{1}{3}; \frac{1}{2}]$

Could you give me some advices?

---

Above is some mistake. It should be

$$
\left.\frac{x^{-5a+1}}{-5a+1} \ln(1+x^{2a}) \right|_{0}^{\infty} + \frac{2a}{1-5a}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-3a}}{(1+x^{2a})} dx
$$

It looks easier. Just one integral left.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^{3a}+x^{5a})} dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x^{3a}+x^{5a})} + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^{3a}+x^{5a})}
$$

Second converges for $a > \frac{1}{5}$ first exists for $a < \frac{1}{3}$. So, for $(\frac{1}{5}; \frac{1}{3})$ it's solved. So now I'll conclude rest.

$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^{-5a} \ln(1+x^{2a}) dx =
\int_0^{1} x^{-5a} \ln(1+x^{2a}) dx + \int_1^{\infty} x^{-5a} \ln(1+x^{2a}) dx
$$

Divergence for $a \geq \frac{1}{3}$ I have, cause near $0$ it's like $x^{-3a}$ and for $a \leq \frac{1}{5}$ cause for big $x$ inequality $\ln(1+x^{2a}) \geq 1$ holds.

Therefore it converges only for $a \in (\frac{1}{5}; \frac{1}{3})$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to ensure integrability in a right neighbourhood of the origin, where the integrand function behaves like $x^{-3a}$, we must have $\text{Re}(a)<\frac{1}{3}$. In a similar way, to ensure integrability in a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$ we must have $\text{Re}(a)>\frac{1}{5}$.

It follows that the given integral is converging for $\text{Re}(a)\in\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{3}\right)$,
 and in such a case its value is given by
$$ I(a) = \frac{\pi}{(5a-1)\cos\frac{\pi}{2a}},\tag{1} $$
since integration by parts brings the integral in something like $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+x^{\beta}}\,dx $, that can be computed through [Euler's Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the [$\Gamma$ reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), by setting $1+x^\beta = u^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. Your way to calculate value is over my experience level. However, is now my proof correct? (On the end, without mistake.)

Comment: @Tacet: your amended proof now looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer.